# keycloak.getAccount() is working while keycloak.protect() is not working

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak

I have an app on MERN stack in which react app runs on port 3000 while nodejs app runs on 3001 in development environment .
I want to integrate Keycloak in app.I started Keycloak instance and created Realm named MERN in which i created two clients one is react which is public client and other is node which is bearer-only client .
I created one user also

I integrated the keycloak on react with react keycloak client configuration and got access token and passed it to Authorization Bearer on backend.
I configured the NodeJs app with node keycloak client ..

keycloak provides method keycloak.protect() to protect Apis which is not working it always gives Access Denied.
There is another method in keycloak getAccount which takes bearer token parameter and returns account in promise object.
I extracted the token from Authorization header and passed it to getAccount which returned account.

For key cloak configuration i download it from installation tab in client and haven't done any tweak just copy pasted code from keycloak nodeJS docs. 
So i am not feeling any need to write code or configuration here.
For testing you can generate app from express-cli and create-react-app.

For reactJs i used library called keycloak-js and for nodeJs i used keycloak-connect.

Question is why keycloak.protect() is not working??
If anyone knows answere please tell me.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: No i was unable to resolve it